# Sort array of objects alphabetically by property with special characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort alphabetically array of objects based on their usernames.
Basically array of users is something like this

```
users = [
{ 
  firstName: 'Ana'
  lastName: 'Smith'
  username: 'Ana'
  id: 1
  email: 'ana@ana.com'
},
{ 
  firstName: 'Ana'
  lastName: 'AnaWithSpecialA'
  username: 'Äna'
  id:2
  email: 'ana2@ana.com'
},
{ 
  firstName: 'Bla'
  lastName: 'Blabla'
  username: 'Bla'
  id:3
  email:'bla@bla.com'
}
]
```

I use this function for sorting:

```
users.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.username < b.username) return -1;
  if(a.username > b.username) return 1;
  return 0
});
```

But users with usernames that start with Ä, Ö, Ü always end up last. This is German alphabet letters btw. How can I push them so that Ä can be behind A and Ö behind O etc, or whatever is the correct way of sorting?

Comment: [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: a.username.localeCompare(b.username)

Comment: There are quotes missing around your property string values.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, It works